# Space between caption and listing

Tags: listings, captions

Obviously, the caption is not beautifully placed; it needs more space between the caption text and the frame/listing itself.

How can I do that?

I am using the `IEEEtran` document class and the package `listings`, if this is important. The related code is

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily, breaklines=true, xleftmargin=2em, frame=single, framexleftmargin=15pt} 
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Search-based change access}, label={lst:query}]
<url>/changes/?q=change:<change_id>&o=LABELS&o=DETAILED_LABELS&o=DETAILED_ACCOUNTS&o=REVIEWER_UPDATES&o=MESSAGES
\end{lstlisting}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, documentclass is important. How is the listing appearing there? Magic? Which package are you using? Do you use it properly? A minimal working example would be needed to tell.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I added a minimal example.

Comment: Usually takes people about half an hour to post a minimal working example. I guess usually they take the time to read what it is and then try to create it. Sorry.

Comment: Is this not sufficient?

Comment: Sorry, i have seen just three lines there. Should be ok.

Comment: Great. Sorry for my first draft. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `caption` package cooperates with `listings`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\lstset{basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily, breaklines=true, xleftmargin=2em, frame=single, framexleftmargin=15pt, belowcaptionskip=8pt}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Search-based change access}, label={lst:query}]
<url>/changes/?q=change:<change_id>&o=LABELS&o=DETAILED_LABELS&o=DETAILED_ACCOUNTS&o=REVIEWER_UPDATES&o=MESSAGES
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]